# Doctrine saves only last collection

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine, fieldset

I need some help, I work on ZF2 with doctrine 2. 
I have one entity: TaFoo with children : TaBar (ArrayCollection) . TaBar has also children: ATypeBar (ArrayCollection) associate to TypeBar.
I use FieldSets to add multiple TaBars and on each TaBar I want add multiple ATypeBars.

But when I save:

- TaFoo is create and save
- TaBar are also create and save
- TaTypeBar save only the last collection

**I don't have any error but the firsts under collections are never save.**

**Entity:** 
*TaFoo*

```
  class TaFoo{
        /**
         * @var integer
         * @ORM\Column(name="ID_FOO", type="integer", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
         * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="TA_FOO_ID_FOO_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
         */

        private $idFoo;
        /**
         * Get idFoo
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getIdFoo()
        {
            return $this->idFoo;
        }

        /**
        * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TaBar", mappedBy="idFoo", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
         **/
        private $idBar;

        /**
         * Get idBar
         *
         * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         */
        public function getIdBar()
        {
            return $this->idBar;
        }
         /**
         * Remove idBar
         *
         * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idBar
         */
        public function removeIdBar(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idBars)
        {
            foreach ($idBars as $idBar) {
                $idBar->setIdFoo(null);
                $this->idBar->removeElement($idBar);
            }
        }
         /**
         * Add idBar
         *
         * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idBar
         * @return TaFoo
         */
        public function addIdBar(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idBars)
        {
            foreach ($idBars as $idBar) {
                $idBar->setIdFoo($this);
                $this->idBar->add($idBar);
            }

            return $this;
            }
}
```

*TaBar*

```
class TaBar {

// **************************************************TYPE BAR***************************************************
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ATypeBar", mappedBy="idBar", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * */
private $idATypeBars;

/**
 * Get typeBar
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getIdATypeBars() {
    return $this->idATypeBars;
}

/**
 * Remove typeBar
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $typeBars
 */
public function removeIdATypeBars(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idATypeBars) {
    foreach ($idATypeBars as $idATypeBar) {
        $idATypeBar->setIdBar(null);
        $this->idATypeBars->removeElement($idATypeBar);
    }
}

/**
 * Add typeBar
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $typeBars
 * @return TaBar
 */
public function addIdATypeBars(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idATypeBars) {
    foreach ($idATypeBars as $idATypeBar) {
        $idATypeBar->setIdBar($this);
        $this->idATypeBars->add($idATypeBar);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

*ATypeBar*

```
class ATypeBar
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID_A_TYPE_Bar", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="A_TYPE_Bar_ID_A_TYPE_Bar_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $idATypeBar;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\TaBar
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\TaBar",cascade={"persist"},inversedBy="idATypeBar")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ID_Bar", referencedColumnName="ID_Bar")
     * })
     */
    private $idBar;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\TaTypeBar
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\TaTypeBar")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ID_TYPE_Bar", referencedColumnName="ID_TYPE_Bar")
     * })
     */
    private $idTypeBar;


    /**
     * Get idATypeBar
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIdATypeBar()
    {
        return $this->idATypeBar;
    }

    /**
     * Set idBar
     *
     * @param \Application\Entity\TaBar $idBar
     * @return ATypeBar
*/
    public function setIdBar(\Application\Entity\TaBar $idBar = null)
    {
        $this->idBar = $idBar;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idBar
     *
     * @return \Application\Entity\TaBar
     */
    public function getIdBar()
    {
        return $this->idBar;
    }

    /**
     * Set idTypeBar
     *
     * @param \Application\Entity\TaTypeBar $idTypeBar
     * @return ATypeBar
     */
    public function setIdTypeBar(\Application\Entity\TaTypeBar $idTypeBar = null)
    {
        $this->idTypeBar = $idTypeBar;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idTypeBar
     *
     * @return \Application\Entity\TaTypeBar
     */
    public function getIdTypeBaru()
    {
        return $this->idTypeBar;
    }
}
```

*TaTypeBar*

```
class TaTypeBar {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ATypeBar", mappedBy="idTypeBar", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * */
    private $typeBar;


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID_TYPE_Bar", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="TA_TYPE_BarDE_ID_TYPE_Bar_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $idTypeBar;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->idBar = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get idTypeBar
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIdTypeBar() {
        return $this->idTypeBar;
    }

    /**
     * Add idBar
     *
     * @param \Application\Entity\TaBar $idBar
     * @return TaTypeBar
     */
    public function addIdBar(\Application\Entity\TaBar $idBar) {
        $this->idBar[] = $idBar;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

**FieldSet**
*TaFoo Fieldset*

```
*[..HERE: Some Elements, they work..]*
//****************************************************************************
// TAB BAR
//****************************************************************************
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
    'name' => 'idBar',
    'options' => array(
        // 'tab' => 'multiple',
        'label' => 'add a bar',
        'count' => 0,
        'allow_remove' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'target_element' => new BarFieldset($entityManager, $userNumeroOrga),
    )
));
$this->get('idBar')->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydratorDateTimeFr($entityManager));
```

*BarFieldset*

```
*[..HERE: Some Elements, they work..]*
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
    'name' => 'idATypeBars',
    'options' => array(
        'tab' => 'Bar',
        'label' => 'add a TypeBar',
        'count' => 1,
        'allow_remove' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'target_element' => new TypeBarFieldset($entityManager),
    )
));
```

**Controller**
*FooController*

```
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $idFoo = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $idFoo = $this->params()->fromPost('idFoo');
    }

    $taFoo = $this->getEntityManager()->find('\Application\Entity\TaFoo', $idFoo);
    $form = new FooForm($this->getEntityManager(), $this->getUserNum());
    $form->bind($taFoo);

    if ($request->isPost()) {

        $post = $request->getPost();

        $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
        $fieldset = $config['fieldset'];

        $form->setData($post);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($taFoo);
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

            echo ('ok');
            exit();
        }

        echo '-1: ';
        print_r($form->getMessages());
        exit();
```

I have already check if datas are correct in $request->getPost and it's ok. All datas to save TaFoo/TaBar/AtypeBar/TaTypeBar are in. But the persist don't work with TaTypeBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [initialize all your collections](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/best-practices.html#initialize-collections-in-the-constructor) in your entity class `__construct` methods.

I think the problem lies there because I don't see any initialization of your `$this->idATypeBars` in your `TaBar` entity.

So add a `__construct` function like this:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->idATypeBars = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Also check the constructors of your other entities. This will definitely cause issues.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I added all ArrayCollection() in construct but  always the same problem. 
This code (Three entities with just manytoone and onetomany) is a bug when you get entities from database with command line.

It's a manytomany. I do some test and it's ok, so when I use manytomany on my entities, i'll edit my question. ;)

Comment: @Kearitt Are you using any [doctrine validator for your mappings](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html#runtime-vs-development-mapping-validation)? Sounds like your problem might be in some invalid associations. One example I can see is that there is no `inversedBy` on your `$idTypeBar` in `ATypeBar` entity. The Validator will help you to get these things right. I actually never have problems with `ManyToOne` and `OneToMany` relations.

Comment: No, we use Reverse engineering. And this method don't create (with oracle database) manytomany. 
In futur others projects, we'll use Validator and generate database from entities. It'll be better.